# How to properly use bootstrap stretch in react-bootstrap grid?

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4, react-bootstrap

I creating a dashboard webapp that has some cards in it as a content wrapper. Due to the different default size of the content, there is a gap that I wanted to get rid of it. Here's the screenshot :

[my problem's screenshoot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H3IX5.png)

I want **Tweet official card** strecthed all the way down so that it has the same size as the other cards in the right.

I used `d-flex align-items-stretch`. It stretched, but the width is shrinked like this :

[after implementing d-flex align-items-stretch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nSoeL.png)

How do I make it fit perfectly to fill the gap ?

PS: I implement this in [React Bootstrap Grid](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/layout/grid/)